# How can i create a custom object_label without adding a new method to the domain class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I notice that RailsAdmin has an object_label method, but it's unclear how to use it:

```
config.model Entity do
  object_label do
    # ???
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model Team do
    object_label_method do
      :custom_label_method
    end
  end

  def custom_label_method
    "Team #{self.name}"
  end
end
```

Extracted from the [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL)

If you just want to use an attribute from the model, you can just pass it as the method to be called... like `:name` would return the `object.name` as the label.